How do I get rid of these weird margin lines in my edit boxes in Delphi FMX
I have this app in Delphi FMX that works great on my desktop. But, after I implemented a dynamic resizing function for the app's window, all of my edit boxes and buttons have these margin lines in them that I can't seem to get rid of.
Has anyone seen these before, or have any insight on how to get rid of them?
I've looked in the properties tab for each edit box and button. The margins are set to 0, and none of the other properties stick out as a culprit.


Which Delphi version you are using? How you implemented the resizing function? Which style are you using? Do you have same issue with different style? We would need to see [mre] to be able to answer this question.

@DalijaPrasnikar, this is a problem with BitmapLinks which can be "fixed" using the BitmapLinks Editor in Style Designer: you need to match the blue squares with the yellow ones for each control state. You can see the same kind of lines that OP is talking about when you use the TScaledLayout component.

@Bruce So you are saying that this is a problem with particular style, not scaling itself?

@DalijaPrasnikar Quite the opposite: I guess what I'm trying to say is that this is a problem with any style that uses BitmapLinks along with scaling. Scaling causes distortion, so it's better to use vector-based styles (with TRectangle as the background) for that.

@Bruce I have reopened the question, so you can write an answer if you know how to solve this issue.

It looks like scaling causes this kind of distortion for (system default?) style that uses BitmapLinks, which you can try to "fix" using the BitmapLinks Editor in the Style Designer. Try editing the default style for each control's state and resolution, like this:

Find the "problem" style object (it is background for EditStyle)



Find the property with TBitmapLinks and press the three dots



Check each state in the Links list and each required resolution (at least 1,00 x) matching the blue squares with the yellow ones as indicated by the arrows



Make sure all the links look like this, apply the changes and see if you still have a problem


Or, even better, you can create your own vector-based style by using the TRectangle as a background:

A more global way to prevent this kind of distortion is to force GDI+ with FMX.Types.GlobalUseDirect2D := false; before Application.Initialize; in your .dpr file. Sometimes this will help. However, it may cause further display problems.

I tried what you suggested verbatim with moving the squares. Scaling within the editor looks great now but when I try to run the app from within the editor and via the .exe file I get a read access violation error.

@Amora015 Changing the style shouldn't cause AV, maybe something else is causing it. Try using a debugger to find the source of the problem.

@Amora015 forcing GDI+ with FMX.Types.GlobalUseDirect2D := false; before Application.Initialize; in your .dpr file sometimes can help to get rid of those lines too.

This worked like a charm! It made a small lag when resizing but totally got rid of the lines

@Amora015 I'm glad it helped to resolve the issue. I will update my answer so that you can accept it.
